# Purpose of votes being cast from non followers of a proposal?

Tags: discussion, support, area-51

What is the purpose in Area 51 for allowing non-followers of a proposal to vote on questions on that particular proposal?

Comment: What would be the purpose of _not_ allowing non-followers of a proposal to vote on questions on that particular proposal?

Comment: IMO, area 51 doesn't get enough participation as it is. Limiting votes to only people who follow would make things take even longer than it already does.

Comment: How does it affect the amount of people required to commit to a proposal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same purpose that any user is allowed to vote on any post in any Stack Exchange site, given he/she got enough reputation on that site.

Sample questions should not be rocket science: they should roughly reflect what the questions on the site are going to look like. Anyone should be able to have a say, regardless of following the proposal or not following.