# Reward system across all stack exchanges for using area 51

Tags: discussion, area-51, site-promotion

Should there be a reward system across all Stack Exchange sites for participating in Area 51 to increase participation in Area 51?

Comment: Why? What is the problem with the current participation? How would a reward system *fix* that problem?

Comment: No need for reward. One way to increase participation is adding top sample questions to the Hot Network Questions list in the sidebar.

Comment: Rene, a high rep user posted to another question that there was not enough participation as is.  Hence why I asked the question.

Comment: Link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246244/purpose-of-votes-being-cast-from-non-followers-of-a-proposal

Comment: @Mhmd Why did you retag this to feature-request? As a discussion question I'm not bothered to vote but for a feature-request this question will get my downvote. Are you sure the OP intended a feature request?

Comment: @rene the question is asking for a "reward system across SE sites", it is not a general discussion about how to increase participation in area51.

Comment: Hmm, that is not how I read it. I read it as a discussion to increase participation and if a reward system is an option to be considered. Maybe the OP can clear this up....

Comment: Ah, thanks @MonicaCellio I was just going to check in the Tavern if I was overlooking something...